# Inserting multiple values using mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

Can anybody tell me what is wrong with this line of code? I am currently new and now trying to use mysqli prepared statement in order to connect to the database back end.
So far I can't seem to get it to update the database.

```
  $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO canada VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)");
    $stmt->bind_param('sssiss',$_REQUEST["UserID"],$_REQUEST["FirstName"],
                        $_REQUEST["LastName"],$_REQUEST["Age"],$_REQUEST["WhatParty"],
                        $_REQUEST["Electorate"]);

    $stmt->execute();
```

Comment: try pdo its  better than mysqli

Comment: PDO is a database abstraction class for mysqli, not better than mysqli it just offers more tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the first parameter to bind param it specifys there are two fields of type integer which is not true.

[Bind parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

if user id and age is int, and rest are string type then 
it should be 
i for integer, s for string

-- Update

```
$db = new mysqli($server_host, $server_user, $server_password, $server_db);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("DB error: %s", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}



$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO canada
                      userid,firstname,lastname,age,whatparty,electorate)
                      VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?))");

$stmt->bind_param("ississ",$_REQUEST["UserID"],$_REQUEST["FirstName"],
                  $_REQUEST["LastName"],$_REQUEST["Age"],
                  $_REQUEST["WhatParty"],$_REQUEST["Electorate"]);


$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: I've corrected my example in the post before the update. But its still not working.

Comment: You also need to make sure that each variable exists in the current scope (You are using superglobals in this instance so you are fine) but also make sure that all of the `$_REQUEST` parameters are set

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that there is 6 `(?,?,?,?,?,?)`   and you 7 parameter in `bind_param`

try

```
 $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO canada VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
```

Comment: 1st parameter means parameter type list. In this case, "sssiss" means String String String Integer String and String.

Comment: Getting an error now: Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/officialWebTestSafer/insertSafer.php on line 12

Comment: is it because the database is using varchar so I can't use string?

Comment: That new error means you're getting an error when assigning to `$db`.