# Simple object sqli insert

Tags: php, object, mysqli, foreach, insert

Hello I'd like to insert all from $_SESSION into rows $key with value $value 
so something like     `foreach ($_SESSION as $key => $value) {}`
Imlooking at:[Best way to INSERT many values in mysqli?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15149157/best-way-to-insert-many-values-in-mysqli)
name of rows in mysqli is same as names of given $key .I need to insert each $value in its $key (row)

Code:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO testtable VALUES (?)";
$stmt = $dbc->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $key);
$mysqli->query("START TRANSACTION");
foreach ($_SESSION as $key => $value) {
    $stmt->execute();
}
$stmt->close();
$mysqli->query("COMMIT");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query has a syntax error, which you never bothered checking for:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO testtable podatki VALUES (?)";
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

If that's really the table name, then it should be quoted with backticks:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `testtable podatki` VALUES (?)";
                      ^-----------------^
```

if `podatki` is a field name, then it should be

```
$query = "INSERT INTO testtable (podatki) VALUES (?)";
                                ^-------^
```

And also never assume that a DB operation succeeded. ALWAYS check for errors:

```
$stmt = $dbc->prepare($query);
if (!$stmt) {
   die(mysqli_error($dbc));
}
```

Comment: sorry, my bad.. should be "INSERT INTO testtable VALUES (?)";

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying that you are trying to call a member function, namely `bind_param()`, on a non-object.

That means that this line:

```
$stmt = $dbc->prepare($query);
```

is not succeeding,

and thus you have an incorrect return value that is set as the value of `$stmt`

so when you try to call `bind_param` it fails because `$stmt` is not the type of object that it was expecting.

Comment: Any idea waht to do? I don't understand the code. object programming in php is confusing to me

Comment: @Newb Add a line after `$stmt = $dbc->prepare($query);` with this code: `var_dump($stmt); die;` and edit your question to post the results.

Comment: bool(false) is what i get. $dbc is the $dbc = new mysqli(stuff..); right? Can you also check logics behind this code.?

Comment: @Newb http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219809/mysqli-prepare-statement-returning-false-but-why

Comment: ok i fixed query, copied something wrong. now i get Column count doesn't match value count at row 1. row one is primary "id" with auto incremnt? what does it mean. there must be a logical problem which i dont understand

Comment: @Newb It means that you are inserting more or less values than there are columns in your database table. Look at the [MySQL syntax for insert](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html).

Comment: Thats true. is there a way to not fill all the columns?

Comment: Only row thats not used is first one. "id" which is primary and auto increment

Comment: Only row thats not used is first one. "id" which is primary and auto increment. there must be logical error. Can you check if this insert all from $_SESSION into rows $key with value $value?

Comment: @Newb When you do the `INSERT` you don't have to specify an `id` when you just use `INSERT VALUES(...)` it is implicit and just auto increments itself. **However** if you want to insert the `id` you have to use the other syntax: `INSERT INTO tbl_name (id,...) VALUES(15,...);`

Comment: no there is no id insert there must be logical error

Comment: @Newb Can you edit your question and show what the columns are in your database table and what values you are inserting in an example row?

Comment: @Newb I believe the problem is you are trying to bind multiple values to a single `?`.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13004870/inserting-multiple-values-using-mysqli

Comment: Hey, i have updated my question. All of the columns are named after $key from $_SESSION  i just need to add their values.